# Where shouldn't I put data attribute on html?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

Can I put html5 data attribute in to the html tag itself or into other tags in the header?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js" data-directory='{json data}'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx/ready.js" data-directory='{json data}'></script>
```

Are these considered as invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can add data attributes to any tag, If its makes sense and it works then I guess its valid.

Answer (score 2):

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#custom-data-attribute) says that it's valid:

> Every HTML element may have any number of custom data attributes specified, with any value.